# View component refresh on button click in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm using view components to render a list of strings in HTML. The component has a button that when clicked, should toggle which list of strings is shown. When the button is clicked, only the view component should be reloaded, not the entire page.

I have the component list showing properly but I'm not sure how to get the button hooked up so that it only refreshes the view component

In ~ViewComponents I have ShowWords:

```
public class ShowWords : ViewComponent
{
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(bool ShowAll)
        {
            if (ShowAll)
            {
                return View(new List<string> { "showing", "all", "of", "the", "strings" });
            } 
            else
            {
                return View(new List<string> { "not", "showing", "all", "strings" });
            }
        }
    }
```

In ~Pages/Shared/Components/ShowWords I have Default.cshtml:

```
@model List<string>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>STRINGS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@Model[i]</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The view component is called with this:

```
<vc:show-words show-all="true" />

@*How do I get this button to refresh the view component?*@
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Toggle"/>
</form>
```

I'm able to get the button working if I bind it to a property and then post it but that reloads the entire screen not just the view component. What's the best way get just the view componenet to refresh when the button's clicked? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ajax to call action which returns a view component.Here is a demo:

View(change input's type to button,so that the form will not be submitted when clicking the button):

```
<div id="component">

    <vc:show-words show-all="true" />
</div>

@*How do I get this button to refresh the view component?*@
<form method="post">
    <input type="button" value="Toggle" onclick="Refresh()"/>
</form>
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        function Refresh() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "RefreshViewComponent",
                success: function (data) {
                    document.getElementById("component").innerHTML = data;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

action:

```
public IActionResult RefreshViewComponent()
        {
            return ViewComponent("ShowWords", new { ShowAll = false });
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Where does the RefreshViewComponent() function go? Does it need to be in a controller or should it be in the code behind for the razor page?

Comment: It's in a controller.